# Manipulating complex power series, finding terms

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

In an exercise I am being asked to find the terms up to order $\leq 3$ in the power series of $$a)\frac{1}{\cos(z)}$$ $$b) \frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}$$

By definition, $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and $\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$, using that $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$, we get $$\sin(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!},$$$$\cos(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

I don't know how to calculate the power series of a) and b) with this information. As a matter of fact, I don't ever understand why does it make sense, I mean, wouldn't we have $z$ to the negative powers (we haven't seen Laurent series so a) and b) have to be power series with non negative exponents)? And isn't $\cos(z)$ $0$ in for some values of $z$? Is the exercise implicitly assuming we are discarding those values and defining a) and b) where it makes sense?

I hope I am expressing clearly where my confussion lays and I would really appreciate if someone could help me with the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{1}{\cos(z)}=\frac{1}{1-\frac12z^2+O(z^4)}$$

Proceeding with long division, we find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{1}{\cos(z)}=1+\frac12z^2+O(z^4)}$$

Similarly, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}&=\frac{z\left(1-\frac16z^2+O(z^4)\right)}{1-\frac12z^2+O(z^4)}\\\\
&=z\left(1-\frac16z^2+O(z^4)\right)\left(1+\frac12z^2+O(z^4)\right)\\\\
&=z\left(1+\frac13z^2+O(z^4)\right)\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{z+\frac13z^3+O(z^5)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't understand why the expression $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}z^2+O(z^4)}=1+\frac{1}{2}z^2+O(z^4)$? Could you explain me the steps to get from one expression to the other? And given that $\cos(z)=0$ for some $z$, isn't $\frac{1}{\cos(z)} not defined at that value?

Comment: For the first question, just perform long division.  Or if you prefer, use the geometric series expasion of $\frac 1{1-r}$ and set $r=\frac12 z^2+O(z^4)$.  For your second question, the radius of convergence of the series for the secant function would be $\pi/2$ as you pointed out.  This expansion is therefore only valid in a disc with radius less than $\pi/2$.